# Alinhamento de imagens no Carrossel

Tags: html

Como posso fazer esse alinhamento central, e que não fique sobreposto no menu header?

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" align="center" class="carousel slide col-md-8" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="5"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="6"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="7"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="8"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="9"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="imagens/flower-stormdesign.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="imagens/flower-stormdesign.jpg" alt="slide 1">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: O que está utilizando para criar o carrossel? E qual é o problema?

Comment: Quero que ele fique no centro da página, mas sem ficar abaixo do menu no header. Mas ja tentei N coisas, e o unico que funcionou melhor, foi inserindo a class="container", mas ainda assim, ficou embaixo do menu.

Estou usando o carousel do Bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Você pode inserir o parâmetro `text-align:center;`no CSS da class ou div que deseja centralizar, por exemplo, caso seja as div poderá utilizar:

```
div {
text-align:center;
}
```

Caso seja uma class deverá usar:

```
.carousel-inner {
    text-align:center;
    }
```

Casos seja uma li deverá usar:

```
.carousel-indicators li {
    text-align:center;
}
```